# saving a hash to serialize Hash column in mysql but getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.19 app which has the following class:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :mig_serializer_frag, Hash
```

I have an after_save callback block that looks like this:

```
  after_save do
    a={}
    a[:name]="Jon"
    a[:last_name]="Johnson"
    self.update_column(:mig_serializer_frag, a)
  end
```

looking at the sql, it produces:

```
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `items` SET `mig_serializer_frag` = '---\n- :name\n- Jon\n','---\n- :last_name\n- Johnson\n' WHERE `items`.`id` = 1
   (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''---\n- :last_name\n- Johnson\n' WHERE `items`.`id` = 1' at line 1: UPDATE `items` SET `mig_serializer_frag` = '---\n- :name\n- Jon\n','---\n- :last_name\n- Johnson\n' WHERE `items`.`id` = 1
from /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
```

I clearly see the error but am I not fully understading what a serialize Hash should be. I thought it was a YAML representation which when brought out of db becomes a Hash. Why would rails generate this update statement and how do I fix it?

### edit #1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is `update_column` rather than anything else in your code. `update_column` doesn't work with serialized attributes as documented in the [rails issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7190).

If you need to set the value `after_save` you might have to convert to yaml yourself:

```
self.update_column(:mig_serializer_frag, a.to_yaml)
```

Comment: interesting disucssion. so this kinda works on getting it in but now Rails sees it as just a string.... ugh...

Comment: You'll still need the `serialize` call. The bit that is failing is the saving of the serialized attribute but it should still retrieve the yaml attribute correctly and deserialize it to a hash again.

Comment: thx Shadwell - like most callbacks, I ended up going from an `after_` to `before_` which allowed for the normal semantics as I didn't need to suppress other callbacks. thx for help

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the column type is `String` for that attribute you're trying to serialize.

Change it to `Text` and rails will be able to perform the conversion to YAML and then serialize it.

Comment: i get what you're saying as I've seen problems with string but we are a Text column (see included screenshot)